# Null reference error adding custom layout to alert dialog

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-alertdialog

I'm creating a custom alert dialog

```
// Biuld the dialog
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

// Create the dialog
AlertDialog alertToShow = alert.create();

// Set keyboard to the dialog
alertToShow.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);

// Add custom layout to the dialog
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null);
alert.setView(dialogView);

// Show the dialog
alertToShow.show();
```

But the following line from above where I add my custom layout

```
f1.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, f1, false));
```

results in the error

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.FrameLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference

Any idea how to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the view after the dialog is displayed or after the layout is inflated. Not before

```
// Add custom layout to the dialog
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, f1, false)
FrameLayout f1 = (FrameLayout) dialogView.findViewById(android.R.id.custom);
f1.addView(dialogView);

// Show the dialog
alertToShow.show();
```

Though, I think you want `alertToShow.setView(dialogView)`, maybe

Answer (score 0):

I have to add views before I create the dialog

```
    // Add custom layout to the dialog
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null);
    alert.setView(dialogView);

    // Create the dialog
    AlertDialog alertToShow = alert.create();

    // Set keyboard to the dialog
    alertToShow.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);

    // Show the dialog
    alertToShow.show();
```